# Copy all static asset contents from public to build folder?

Tags: npm, package.json

I'm trying to build out my project for production and I'm having a hard time copying all my static files over to my build folder. When I run my npm script, it copies everything to my build folder but when it copies, it brings the entire `public` directory with it. I just want to copy everything inside of the public directory and copy it over to my build folder for production. However, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my npm script.

Here is my code:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --progress --color --profile --config webpack.development.config.js --mode development --hot",
    "clean": "rm -rf build public/bundle.js && rm -rf build public/bundle.js.gz",
    "server": "nodemon server/main.js",
    "sass": "node-sass -w public/assets/scss -o public/assets/css/ --recursive",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run sass\" \"npm run client\"",
    "prod": "npm run clean && webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --mode production --progress --colors --profile",
    "prod:cp": "cp ./package.json build/ && cp ./dbconnection.js build/ && cp ./webpack.development.config.js build/ && cp -R ./services build/ && cp -R ./routes build/ && cp -R ./public build/ && cp -R ./models build/"
  }
}
```

Screenshot after I run the "prod:cp" npm command:

[image: Build Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change `cp -R ./public build/` to `cp -R ./public/. build/`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --progress --color --profile --config webpack.development.config.js --mode development --hot",
    "clean": "rm -rf build public/bundle.js && rm -rf build public/bundle.js.gz",
    "server": "nodemon server/main.js",
    "sass": "node-sass -w public/assets/scss -o public/assets/css/ --recursive",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run sass\" \"npm run client\"",
    "prod": "npm run clean && webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --mode production --progress --colors --profile",
    "prod:cp": "cp ./package.json build/ && cp ./dbconnection.js build/ && cp ./webpack.development.config.js build/ && cp -R ./services build/ && cp -R ./routes build/ && cp -R ./public/. build/ && cp -R ./models build/"
  }
}
```